# Capacitors draining battery in typical design MCP73831

Tags: capacitor, integrated-circuit, charging, lipo, wearable

**Background**

I am an electronics hobbyist and working as a software engineer. I would like to make my own wearable rechargable device (Nixie watch). In fact, I already made a Nixie watch and used an external Adafruit Li-po charger (based on the [MCP73831](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP73831-Family-Data-Sheet-DS20001984H.pdf)).

Now I would like to make a better version of the watch and integrate the recharge logic on the PCB. I ordered some MCP73831s and started to read the data sheet.

**Questions**

According to the data sheet, the typical (recommended) setup of the MCP73831 IC uses a 4.7 μF capacitor on the input and output pins. My device will use a small lipo battery (150 mAh,) so small capacitors may be a problem. (Pin 2 from SW1 in the design will go to the rest of the board.)

1. Won't these capacitors (C15 and C16) drain the Li-po battery in my design when the device (watch) is turned off and the charger is disconnected? The battery will always be connected.
2. Do I understand correctly that the mentioned capacitors are primarily recommended when the battery is disconnected (please check image from datasheet)? It may not be a problem for me since the battery will always be connected to the IC.

My design:

[image: my design]

Design from datasheet:

[image: design from datasheet]

External capacitor information from datasheet:

[image: info about caps]

Comment: How much leakage (in uA, nA, etc) can you tolerate based on your desired runtime? What did the datasheets of the caps you found say about the amount of leakage they are expected to have?

Comment: I don't know (sorry). I want to recharge the device as little as possible (of course), so I am curious if those capacitors are actually needed in my situation or that I can leave them out (and there are no active capacitors on the small lipo battery when the nixies are turned off)

Comment: In theory, capacitors will not drain your circuit because they are open-circuit to DC voltages.   Datasheet clearly recommends they be present whether your battery is connected or not (You posted such above "In addition, the battery interconnections appear inductive at high frequencies....")   Use ceramic capacitors, not electrolytic.  They will have virtually zero leakage current and can physically be very small.  Very very small even.   e.g.   https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/281/1/GRT21BC71H475KE13_01-1989585.pdf

Comment: The leakage on this device is typically 250 na, max 2 uA.  If using ceramic capacitors as Kyle B suggests, this will be your largest leakage.